# Inventory save and load items android

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

can't realize the correct work of saving and loading items in the inventory. In one session and between scenes saving and loading works. But if I re-enter the game, then either part of the items disappears or all items (as I noticed perhaps the problem is exactly in saving and loading Sprite) because in the list of items they are, the player does not see the UI items after re-entry. Can anyone suggest how to fix it ? I am a beginner.

```
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Item", menuName = "Inventory/Item")]
public class Item : ScriptableObject
> {
new public string name = "New Item";
public Sprite icon = null;
public bool idDefaulItem = false;


public virtual void Use()
>     {
Debug.Log("Using " + name);
>     }

public void RemoveFromInventory()
>     {
Inventory.Instance.Remove(this);
>     }
> }
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using TMPro;

public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region Singleton

    public static Inventory Instance;

    private void Awake()
    {
       Instance = this;
       LoadInventory();
    }
    #endregion
    // Event handler for when items are changed
    public delegate void OnItemChanged();
    public OnItemChanged onItemChangedCallback;

    public int slots = 20;
    public List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
    float coinValue;
    public bool Add(Item item)
    {
        if (items.Count >= slots)
        {
            Debug.Log("Inventory is full");
            return false;
        }

        items.Add(item);
        if (onItemChangedCallback != null)
            onItemChangedCallback.Invoke();
        SaveInventory();
        return true;
    }

    public void Remove(Item item)
    {
        items.Remove(item);
        if (onItemChangedCallback != null)
            onItemChangedCallback.Invoke();
        SaveInventory();
    }
    public void RemoveAllItems()
    {
        items.Clear();
        if (onItemChangedCallback != null)
            onItemChangedCallback.Invoke();
        SaveInventory(); 
    }
    public void ClearInventory()
    {
        items.Clear();
        if (onItemChangedCallback != null)
            onItemChangedCallback.Invoke();
        SaveInventory();
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        
    }
    public void SellRandomValue()
    {
        int coinValue = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Coins");
        int randomCoin = 0;

        if (items.Count >= 1)
        {
            randomCoin = Random.Range(1, 5);
        }
        if (items.Count >= 5)
        {
            randomCoin = Random.Range(5, 15);
        }
        if (items.Count >= 10)
        {
            randomCoin = Random.Range(10, 25);
        }

        coinValue += randomCoin; // Add the random coin value to the current coin value
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Coins", coinValue);
    }
    public void SaveInventory()
    {
        // Convert the inventory data to a JSON string
        string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(this);

        // Define the file path for the save file using the persistent data path
        string filePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "inventory_save.txt");

        // Write the JSON string to the file
        File.WriteAllText(filePath, json);

        Debug.Log("Inventory saved to " + filePath);

    }

    public void LoadInventory()
    {
        // Define the file path for the save file using the persistent data path
        string filePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "inventory_save.txt");

        // Check if the save file exists
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            // Read the JSON string from the file
            string json = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

            // Convert the JSON string back to inventory data
            JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(json, this);

            Debug.Log("Inventory loaded from " + filePath);

        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("No inventory save file found");
        }
    }
}
```

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
public class InventorySlot : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image icon;
    public Button removeButton; 
    Item item;

    AudioSource audioSource;
    public AudioClip UseItemClip;
    void Start()
    {
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }
    public void AddItem (Item newitem)
    {
        item = newitem;

        icon.sprite = newitem.icon;
        icon.enabled = true;

        removeButton.interactable = true;
    }

    public void ClearSlot()
    {
        item = null;

        icon.sprite = null;
        icon.enabled = false;

        removeButton.interactable = false;
    }

    public void OnRemoveButton()
    {
        
        Inventory.Instance.Remove(item);
    }
    public void RemoveAll()
    {
        Inventory.Instance.ClearInventory();
    }

    public void UseItem()
    {
        if (item != null) 
        {
            audioSource.PlayOneShot(UseItemClip);
            item.Use();
        }
    }
    public void TransferToChest()
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            if (Chest.Instance.Add(item))
            {
                Inventory.Instance.Remove(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class InventoryUI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform itemsParent;

    Inventory inventory;

    InventorySlot[] slots;

    EquipmentManager equipmentManager;

    void Start()
    {
      
        equipmentManager = EquipmentManager.Instance;
        equipmentManager.LoadEquipment();

        inventory = Inventory.Instance;
       

        inventory.onItemChangedCallback += UpdateUI;

        slots = itemsParent.GetComponentsInChildren<InventorySlot>();
        UpdateUI(); // Update the UI when the script starts

      
    }

    void UpdateUI()
    {
      
        for (int i = 0;i < slots.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i < inventory.items.Count)
            {
                slots[i].AddItem(inventory.items[i]);
            }
            else
            {
               slots[i].ClearSlot();
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't invoke `onItemChangedCallback` after you `LoadInventory` - so how does the inventory UI get updated?

Comment: @UnholySheep sry if use if `(onItemChanged Callback != null)
onItemChanged Callback.Invoke()` in `LoadInventory` then everything will work correctly?

Comment: Maybe? I just commented on what i observed, you still have to try and debug things yourself to make sure they really do what you expect them to

Comment: @UnholySheep I tried and launched it on Android, it didn't help(UI icon items also disappear after restarting game(